# Получение токена в Тинькофф

Tags: python, json, token

Создали терминал, получили код терминала. Делает POST запрос всё ОК.

Но хочу проверить статус оплаты, и выдаёт такую ошибку

```
{'Success': False, 'ErrorCode': '204', 'Message': 'Неверные параметры.', 'Details': 'Неверный токен. Проверьте пару TerminalKey/SecretKey.'}
```

Получил Токен в разделе Интеграции, но не работает.

Может кто-нибудь знает правильную последовательность действий как получить этот Токен, Тех.поддержка не знает...

Заранее спасибо!

ПРАВКА (код проверки запроса)

```
TINKOFF_API_URL_get="https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/v2/GetState"

async def check_payment_status(order_id: int):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(
             TINKOFF_API_URL_get,
             json={
                 "TerminalKey": Ter_key,
                "Token" : TIN_TOKEN,
                 "PaymentId": order_id  
             }
         ) as response:
             data = await response.json()
             print(data)
             if data["Success"]:
                 return data["Status"]
             else:
                 return None
```

Comment: А код ваш где? Только замажте конкретные токены (замените звёздочками).

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил код запроса на проверку статуса

Comment: `json={` вы в этой строчке уверены?

Comment: А что в ней не так ? Просто делаю запрос на оплату, ссылку все даёт , все работает